# Loop over Json object -- React

Tags: reactjs

I have a API for which I would like to loop over to get all the value of its keys. But unfortunately Iam only getting the keys for it.

My code until now:

```
...
  const image_link = JSON.stringify(image);
  const parsed_link = JSON.parse(image_link);
  console.log('1st link', parsed_link[0].Header)   // gives "abc.jpg"
...
...
      <div>
        {
          Object.keys(parsed_link).map((e, i) => {
            console.log(parsed_link);
            console.log(e);   // gives integers like 0,1,2 etc...
            console.log(i);   // gives integers like 0,1,2 etc...
              <img src={e} alt="something" width="300" height="200" />;
              return null;
          })
        }
      </div>
...
...
```

API looks like this:

```
                "Header": [
                    {
                        "image": "abc.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "image": "xyz.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "image": "lmn.jpg"
                    }
                ]
```

Please suggest, where am I goin wrong.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `const image_link = JSON.stringify(image);` what is the value of image here?

Comment: You are doing `.map()` on `Object.keys(parsed_link)` which is the keys, and why you are only getting keys. Try `parsed_link.map( ... )`

Comment: Removed `django-restframework` tag as it seems irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to loop through an array, you can use `map` function.
If you want to loop through an object, you can have to convert the object into an array using `Object.keys(YOUR_OBJECT)` (if you want to get the key) or `Object.values(YOUR_OBJECT)` (if you want to get the values) than use `map` function.

You can directly print the array of data into an array of views. You have to return a view like these:

```js
YOUR_ARRAY.map((item, index) => (
    <div>YOUR VIEW</div>
))

// or

YOUR_ARRAY.map((item, index) => {
    return(
        <div>YOUR VIEW</div>
    )
})
```

Note: you can only return a single parent view inside the return value. If you want to return multiple views inside the return value, you have to wrap them inside a single `<div></div>` or `<React.Fragment></React.Fragment>` or `<></>` parent.

In your code, I saw you wrote `parsed_link[0].Header`. So I assume that the API returns something like this:

```js
[
    {
        "Header": [
            {
                "image": "abc.jpg"
            },
            {
                "image": "xyz.jpg"
            },
            {
                "image": "lmn.jpg"
            }
        ],
        ...
    },
    ...
]
```

Here is my answer:

```js
<div>
    {
        parsed_link[0]['Header'].map((item, index) => (
            <img 
                key={index}
                src={item} 
                alt='something' 
                width='300' 
                height='200' 
            />
        )
    }
</div>
```

Comment: If mapping an object, getting the array of values is probably more useful, i.e. `Object.values(object).map(value => ...`, or getting the array of entries if you need both the key and value when mapping, i.e. `Object.entries(object).map(([key, value]) => ...`.